# Adding the values of columns in a two dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

Hi I am trying to add rows and columns in the individual elements of an array. I am able to add rows but not the columns.  Below I have a two dimensional array and my loop to add rows produces what I want, however I cannot add the elements of a column together.  I'm stumped on how to do that, I cannot figure out how to add all the numbers together and was hoping someone could help me figure this out.  Thanks in advance.  Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    const int ROW1 = 29;
    const int COL1 = 5;
    int days[ROW1][COL1] =
    {
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 
    };

//code that sums each row in the array and displays the results.

    for (int k = 0; k < ROW1; k++)
    {
        int rowAdder = 0;
        for (int l = 0; l < COL1; l++)
        {
            rowAdder += days[k][l];
        }
        cout << "The total of row " << k + 1 << " is " << rowAdder << "." << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

//code that sums each column in the array and displays the results.

    for (int m = 0; m < ROW1; m++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < COL1; n++)
        {
            int columnAdder = 0;
            columnAdder += days[m][n];
            cout << columnAdder << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output for rows is the following:

```
The total of row 1 is 15.
The total of row 2 is 15.
The total of row 3 is 15.
The total of row 4 is 15.
The total of row 5 is 15.
The total of row 6 is 15.
The total of row 7 is 15.
The total of row 8 is 15.
The total of row 9 is 15.
The total of row 10 is 15.
The total of row 11 is 15.
The total of row 12 is 15.
The total of row 13 is 15.
The total of row 14 is 15.
The total of row 15 is 15.
The total of row 16 is 15.
The total of row 17 is 15.
The total of row 18 is 15.
The total of row 19 is 15.
The total of row 20 is 15.
The total of row 21 is 15.
The total of row 22 is 15.
The total of row 23 is 15.
The total of row 24 is 15.
The total of row 25 is 15.
The total of row 26 is 15.
The total of row 27 is 15.
The total of row 28 is 15.
The total of row 29 is 15.
```

I want the second loop to have a similar output but the numbers won't add if you run the code, it couts the individual elements.  Instead.  Thanks again.

Comment: A computer does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do. You told the computer to execute two nested `for` loops, and then, inside the second loop: 1) set  `columnAdder` to 0. 2) Add to it the value of the cell; 3) Print the result. And that's exactly what your computer did. Obviously, this is not going to add up any column. This occurs for each individual cell in your matrix. If you actually want to add up all values in each column, you'll have to have a `for` loop that does that.

Comment: Why 29 rows? I'm, pretty sure you can demonstrate the problem with 2, 3 tops.

Comment: Maybe go over how the row adder works and think about how to do the same thing for columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reverse the order of your loops :

```
for (int m = 0; m < ROW1; m++)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < COL1; n++)
    {
        int columnAdder = 0;
        columnAdder += days[m][n];
        cout << columnAdder << endl;
    }
}
```

should be :

```
for (int n = 0; n < COL1; n++)
{
    int columnAdder = 0;
    for (int m = 0; m < ROW1; m++)
    {
        columnAdder += days[m][n];
    }
    cout << "The total of column " << n + 1 << " is " << columnAdder << endl;
}
```

Notice how that is similar to what you do for `rowAdder`.  The difference is the order of the loops.

Answer (score 0):

This gets you the total sum.

```
int totalSum = 0;

for (int m = 0; m < ROW1; m++)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < COL1; n++)
    {
        totalSum += days[m][n];  
    }
}
cout << "Total sum: " << totalSum << endl;
```

And by column:

```
for (int n = 0; n < COL1; n++)
{
    cout << "The total of Column " << n << ": ";
    for (int m = 0; m < ROW1; m++)
    {
        int columnAdder = 0;
        columnAdder += days[m][n];
        cout << columnAdder << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To show the sum in a column, you need to first choose one column and then loop through rows, so:

```
sum1 = 0 
for (int m = 0; m < ROW1; m++)
{
    sum1 += days[m][0];  
}
cout << "Total sum in column 1: " << sum1 << endl;
```

To loop through all the column you need to add a second loop:

```
for (int n = 0; n < COL1; n++)
{
      int columnSum = 0;
     for (int m = 0; m < ROW1; m++)
    {
        columnSum += days[m][n];  
    }
    cout << "Column sum: " << columnSum << endl;
}
```

So the loops are reversed compared to when calculating the rows.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic problem, and a syntactical problem. First of all, this loop:

```
for (int m = 0; m < ROW1; m++)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < COL1; n++)
    {
        int columnAdder = 0;
        columnAdder += days[m][n];
        cout << columnAdder << endl;
    }
}
```

Your code is iterating through every column first, and then within that iterating through every row. So, even if it were working like you think it should, you would still be traversing the wrong way.

Another problem you have is that you've declared `columnAdder` within the scope of the `for` loop. This means that for every iteration of that loop you are redeclaring the variable, assigning it to the current element you're at and then printing it. So, that's why you're printing every element.

What you want is this:

```
for (int m = 0; m < COL1; m++)
{
    int columnAdder = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < ROW1; n++)
    {
        columnAdder += days[n][m];
    }
    cout << columnAdder << endl;
}
```

Notice how you are now looping over every column first, and then for each iteration you redeclare a `columnAdder` variable and loop through each row to get your answer.